# Custom object detection with tflite

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I made a project based on raspberry pi to detect custome objects. The .tflite file i got from Google Cloud. My first model I made about two months ago, and everything worked fine. Yesterday I trained my updated dataset and got some troubles. When I try to run the script I get next error:

```
Loading model...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TFLite-PiCamera-od.py", line 84, in <module>
    interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR)
  File "/home/pi/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 207, in __init__
    custom_op_registerers_by_func))
ValueError: Op builtin_code out of range: 130. Are you using old TFLite binary with newer model?Registration failed.
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the TF version, used for the inference is lower than the TF version for the conversion. Please consider ugrading the TensorFlow version in the raspberry pi. Instead of using the tflite_runtime, please consider using the full TensorFlow version.

Comment: Thank you, Jae, for your respond, but I have the newest package of tflite_runtime (it's extension from tensorflow, for edge devices)

Comment: Please check out the based TF version of the tflite_runtime. It can be a lower version.